# select rows where count of 2 fields is greater than 1 with where clause

Tags: mysql

I have a table that looks like this:

```
╔════╦═════════╦═════════╦═══════╗  
║ id ║ deleted ║ status  ║  ref  ║  
╠════╬═════════╬═════════╬═══════╣  
║  1 ║       0 ║ pending ║ 10001 ║  
║  2 ║       0 ║ paid    ║ 10001 ║  
║  3 ║       0 ║ paid    ║ 10001 ║  
║  4 ║       0 ║ paid    ║ 10002 ║  
║  5 ║       1 ║ pending ║ 10002 ║  
║  6 ║       1 ║ paid    ║ 10002 ║  
║  7 ║       0 ║ pending ║ 10003 ║  
║  8 ║       0 ║ paid    ║ 10003 ║  
║  9 ║       0 ║ paid    ║ 10003 ║  
║ 10 ║       0 ║ paid    ║ 10003 ║  
║ 11 ║       0 ║ pending ║ 10004 ║  
║ 12 ║       0 ║ paid    ║ 10004 ║  
║ 13 ║       1 ║ pending ║ 10005 ║  
║ 14 ║       1 ║ paid    ║ 10005 ║  
║ 15 ║       1 ║ paid    ║ 10005 ║  
║ 16 ║       0 ║ paid    ║ 10005 ║  
║ 17 ║       0 ║ pending ║ 10006 ║  
║ 18 ║       0 ║ paid    ║ 10006 ║  
║ 19 ║       0 ║ paid    ║ 10006 ║  
╚════╩═════════╩═════════╩═══════╝
```

I am trying to write a MySQL query that will return the rows that are `paid` and not `deleted`. **But only where the count of `paid` is greater than 1.**  So the result should be:

```
╔════╦═════════╦════════╦═══════╗
║ id ║ deleted ║ status ║  ref  ║
╠════╬═════════╬════════╬═══════╣
║  2 ║       0 ║ paid   ║ 10001 ║
║  3 ║       0 ║ paid   ║ 10001 ║
║  8 ║       0 ║ paid   ║ 10003 ║
║  9 ║       0 ║ paid   ║ 10003 ║
║ 10 ║       0 ║ paid   ║ 10003 ║
║ 18 ║       0 ║ paid   ║ 10006 ║
║ 19 ║       0 ║ paid   ║ 10006 ║
╚════╩═════════╩════════╩═══════╝
```

I have been trying to get this using the following query, but it doesn't do what I need and I now seem to be going around in circles.  Could someone give me a hand?

`SELECT t1.* 
FROM orders t1
WHERE exists 
      (SELECT *
      FROM orders t2 
      where t1.id != t2.id 
      and t1.ref = t2.ref
      and t1.deleted = 0
      and t1.status = 'paid')`

Many thanks!

*[edit] arrgh! Sorry folks, I forgot to say that I need to only return the rows that have more than 1 `paid` status... sorry...*

Comment: Does `SELECT t1.* FROM orders t1 WHERE t1.status = 'paid' and t1.deleted = 0;` not work for you?

Comment: I've edited my question, so sorry for not spotting this when I originally posted

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please play around with the following (don't have a DB instance around):

```
SELECT t.*
FROM orders t
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT ref, deleted, status
    FROM orders
    WHERE deleted = 0 and status = 'paid'
    GROUP BY ref
    HAVING count(ref) > 1
) d
ON t.ref = d.ref
AND t.status = d.status
AND t.deleted = d.deleted;
```

(based on http://www.sqlteam.com/forums/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=68374)

Comment: thanks, but this is also returning `pending` status rows when used on the table I posted

Comment: Sorry, I missed the fact that you can have the same `ref` for `pending` and `paid` statuses. Please see the fixed statement.

Answer (score 1):

Give this a bash:

```
select o.*
from orders o
inner join
(
 select ref, 
 sum(case when status = 'paid' then 1 else 0 end) as paid_count,
 count(distinct status) as total_distinct_status_count
 from orders yt
 where deleted = 0
 group by ref
) t1 on t1.ref = o.ref
where o.status = 'paid'
and o.deleted = 0
and t1.paid_count > 1
and t1.total_distinct_status_count > 1;
```

seems to give the answer that you have posted given the data posted.

Comment: thanks, but it doesn't seem to return what I need.  When used on the same data as I posted, it also returns `12 | 0 | paid | 10004`

Comment: Whoops. So it is. Post amended.

Answer (score -2):

I THINK you are trying too hard to solve this query...
Take a break and start ur code again.
Anyways answer is already given in 1st answer...
Chilllllll